# zeromq pgm unrecoverable data detection

Tags: zeromq, pgm-protocol

I am working on a system in which each node both has a PUB and a SUB. If one of these nodes should be disconnected for quite a long time, it should be able to retrieve data from a more data-secure storage, like a database somewhere in the network. Communication happens over the ePGM protocol.

As I have learned so far, PGM is able to detect an unrecoverable data loss. From zeromq there appears to be a monitor function, however, from what I get in the documentation, it looks as if it can only monitor connection oriented protocols.

Would there be a way of "hooking" into this "unrecoverable data" event or get a disconnect/reconnect event from zeromq?